# require.js + backbone.js --define requirements based on condition from router

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

Ok, I am trying to pass a variable from the router to conditionally require certain views/templates based on the route.

Here is an example route:

```
app_router.on('route:showDashboardView', function () {
        var dashboardView = new DashboardView({pageID:1, gridID:1, modal_view:'views/modalView'});
    });
```

Here is an example view definition:

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'routers/router',
'text!templates/_header.html',
'text!templates/_dashboard.html',
'models/UserSetupModel',
'collections/UserSetupCollection',
'collections/PageSetupCollection',
'views/globalView',
'modal',
'validation',
 //I would like the "modal_view" here.
], function ($, _, Backbone, Router, HeaderTemplate, DashboardTemplate, UserSetupModel, UserSetupCollection, PageSetupCollection, GlobalView, modal, validation, ModalView){
    'use strict'; 
//...etc
```

I guess it does not need to pass through the router...as I don't think that is possible. As I am loading the router.

Just looking for an idea on how this might be accomplished.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to alter the dependencies for your view at run time. But you can require the *modal_view* definition before instantiating your view and passing the class as a parameter. Something like

```
app_router.on('route:showDashboardView', function () {
    require(['views/modalView'], function(ModalView) {
        var dashboardView = new DashboardView({
            pageID: 1,
            gridID: 1, 
            modal_view: ModalView
        });
    });
});
```